# "Regret" vs. "remorse"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

I would like to better understand when I have to use *regret* and when *remorse*.

In Italian we have two words:

- *Rimpianto*: used when I'm sad because I didn't do something in the past (e.g. I didn't buy a staff and now it costs the double).
- *Rimorso*: used when I'm sad because I did something wrong in the past (e.g. I offended a friend and now we don't talk anymore).

I read the dictionary and it seems that the word *regret* can be used as the world *rimorso*.

> A feeling of sadness, repentance, or disappointment over something
>   that has happened or been done.

The word *remorse*, on the other hand, confused me because it is defined as

> Deep regret or guilt for a wrong committed.

So, what are the correspondence of *rimorso* and *rimpianto* in English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remorse is deeper and stronger than regret.  One sense of  regret is

> A feeling of sadness, repentance, or disappointment over something that has happened or been done.

You may have associated *regret* with Italian "*rimorso*" because a deed was done.  But *regret* is not limited to the above sense; it can **also** be used to talk about deeds that weren't done, *ie* also has sense

> A feeling of sadness, repentance, or disappointment over something that **hasn't** happened or **hasn't** been done.

*Regret* thus seems to correspond with your "*rimpianto*" in that, in your example, you focus on the deleterious consequences of an action (or inaction).

As well, *regret* may be used of acts (of commission or omission) performed by **others**.

---

*Remorse* addresses the speaker's moral sense of personal guilt. It is directed inward, a gnawing feeling of distress over one's own responsibility for one's own grave error—in many cases a sense of having sinned; while *regret* is directed outward—an unmoralized feeling of distress over the unhappy consequences of an act which may have been performed (or omitted) by anyone.

So *remorse* can be your *rimorso* if, in your example, you are using the same sense of "doing something *wrong*."

Comment: I suggest a slight expansion: one may also *regret* something somebody else did.

Comment: +1 But remorse could also be felt for an act *not* done if the person feeling remorse had a serious duty to act. "He felt remorse over his failure to enter the burning building to save his child."

Comment: These are all true, @StoneyB, bib. Thanks for pointing them out. Please feel free to edit my answer as you see fit

Comment: @CoolElf, not at all; I had been about to approve (and improve) SB's edit when FF rejected it as changing too much of your answer.

Comment: I see. I'm sorry to hear that, @jwpat7. The way I see it, all answers posted in our community are open for improvement. But then I also know that, like you said, moderators and other members are careful not to change people's original intentions. I'm grateful for the entire system and trust both your and FF's judgment. I could've also inserted SB's idea myself, but I wondered how to fit it in the pretty compact structure. If you'd like to give the edit another try and if there's anything I can do at my end, please tell me

Comment: @CoolElf, you'll need to resolve the struck-out paragraph vs the one after it; I didn't know what to do there, and merely copied in StoneyB's text and ruled through yours.  Also, the paragraph before the **** line is SB's text - I don't quite see the fit.

Comment: Got it. I think the answer can do away with the entire struck-out paragraph. I'll switch the two paragraphs right above the ***, then remove that disruptive line as well.

Comment: @jwpat7, In the end, I kept the ***. I think it's fine now. But my editing has removed mention (next to my avatar) of your contribution

Comment: *Regret* can also be a verb: "I regret my decision". One would not use *remorse* this way.

Answer (score 6):

The meanings overlap, but they are not the same.

An easy way to get the idea is that regret is for doing something stupid while remorse is for doing something immoral.

You lend your neighbour some money and he leaves town without paying it back - you may regret lending him that money, but probably wouldn't feel remorse.

You have an affair and get caught, your wife is heartbroken, then you may well feel remorse for what you did (though possibly not regret!)

Answer (score 0):

I would like here to expand a little the research that maybe someone could find interesting.
As correctly explained above, "rimorso" in italian is the pain for something done, similar to the english "remorse". But, differently, it doesn't mean repentance, repentance is a desire to repair (which is a step further). 
"Rimpianto" is the pain for something lost or not done, and derives from the word "pianto" which means "cry". The link between the english and the italian for the word regret is the verb "regrettare":

> regrettare v. tr. [dal fr. regretter «rimpiangere»], ant. e raro. –
>   Rimpiangere: alcune anime sensibili e filosofiche regrettarono persino
>   l’antico stato selvaggio (Beccaria).

Which comes from the french "regretter", to cry for something that is lost.